# Where can I find Release Notes for minor Versions of Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Typescript verison 4.9 is described here:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/

I wonder where I can find the differences between 4.9.4 and 4.9.3 or in general release notes for minor versions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the best source - a collection of github issues that was solved by that minor version.

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/milestones